# swift multiple cell subclasses in UITableViewCOntroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, swift

i'm trying to add multiple subclasses into a UITableView. The problem is that it keep giving me following error:

```
Type UITableVieCell does not conform to protocol NilLiteralConvertible
```

## CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.section1[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator

        return cell

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SwitchViewCell

        cell.cellLabel?.text = self.section2[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You are not allowed to return nil for cellForRowAtIndexPath

You could use at the end:

```
let cell:UITableViewCell!
return cell
```

instead of

```
 return nil
```

This should be (if you just have 2 sections) never get executed.

Edit:

You could also use instead of "} else if indexPath.section == 1 {" only } else { - to return a cell. I just showed up what is the problem. Or use a Switch/Case and returning an empty Cell on default.

Comment: He could also use instead of "} else if indexPath.section == 1 {" only } else { - to return a cell. I just showed up what is the problem. Or use a Switch/Case and returning an empty Cell on default.

Answer (score 9):

You can't return nil. Instead by default return empty cell.

```
    var cell :UITableViewCell!

    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.section1[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        break;

    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SwitchViewCell
        (cell as SwitchViewCell).cellLabel?.text = self.section2[indexPath.row]
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return cell
```

Make sure that you have registered the nib

```
 self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "SwitchViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "SwitchViewCell")
```

Answer (score 6):

`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` must return a `UITableViewCell` and can't return `nil`. So you will have to remove `return nil`. But it won't be enough. Your `if else` statement also has to be complete. What it means is that every possible `section` value has to be provided or, at least, send to a fallthrough.

Your `if else` statement should look like this:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    /* ... */
} else if indexPath.section == 1 { 
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

Or like this:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    /* ... */
} else {
    /* ... */
}
```

However, the following `if else` statement is not complete:

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    /* ... */
} else if indexPath.section == 1 { 
    /* ... */
}
```

In this case, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` will not know what to return if any of these conditions is verified. Thus, if you try it, Xcode (that is smart) will also display an error message:

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'UITableViewCell'

Therefore, the following code should work:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.section1[indexPath.row]
        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator

        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SwitchViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SwitchViewCell

        cell.cellLabel?.text = self.section2[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

**PS:**

If you also use `switch` statement inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in order to set your cells, [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26164240/1966109) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I did the following:

```
let cellOne = mTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellOne") as! customTableViewCellOne
let cellTwo = mTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellTwo") as! customTableViewCellTwo

if (..something...) { 
    cellOne.mLabel = "hey"
    return cellOne
}

else if (..another condition..) {
    cellTwo.mButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    return cellTwo
}
return UITableViewCell()
```

I hope it helps