# cant return cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

i'm trying to return different cells in a tableView. Normally in this case i would return different cells and then return nil at the bottom, but in this case it gives me and error. I've tried returning an empty cell as well, but also gives me and error.

What i've tried

```
return nil
```

and

```
 var cell: UITableViewCell!
  return cell
```

but both returned errors. How can i fix this?

## cellForRowAtIndex

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    
    
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {


        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        var imageFile = cell.viewWithTag(100) as PFImageView
        imageFile.image = itemFile


        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cell
        
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("segmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        var titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as UILabel?
        titleLabel?.text = itemTitle
        
        let segmentControl = cell.viewWithTag(102) as UISegmentedControl
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = segment
        segmentControl.setTitle("Beskrivelse", forSegmentAtIndex: 0)
        segmentControl.setTitle("Sælger", forSegmentAtIndex: 1)
        segmentControl.setTitle("Lokation", forSegmentAtIndex: 2)
        segmentControl.tintColor = UIColor(rgba: "#619e00")
        var font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Regular", size: 11)
        var attributes:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: font , forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
        segmentControl.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        segmentControl.addTarget(self, action: "segmentAction:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        
        return cell
      
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        switch segment {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellZero", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DescViewCell
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as SellerViewCell
            return cell
        case 2:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as LocationViewCell
            return cell
        default:
            break
        
        }
    }
        
    
    var cell: UITableViewCell!
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mustn't return nil from cellForRowAtIndexPath. You always should return a valid cell.

```
 var cell: UITableViewCell!
```

This line of code doesn't create any cell, it just a UITableViewCell variable with nil content, you have to assign a value to it:

```
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
return cell
```

Answer (score 5):

As indicated in a [previous answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26142330/1966109), `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` must return a `UITableViewCell`. So you can't return `nil`. However, I would also recommend to avoid returning the following codes at the end of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` when you use *if else* or *switch* statements inside it:

```
//bad code design
var cell: UITableViewCell!
return cell
```

or:

```
//bad code design
var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
return cell
```

You can do better code than creating an `UITableViewCell` instance that is never called just in order to silent Xcode warnings!

**So what would be the solution?**

The key thing is to be sure that your last possible value for an *if else* statement is set in `else` (not in `else if`). In the same way, the key thing is to be sure that your last possible value for a *switch* statement is set in `default:` (not in `case XXX:`).

Thus, your code should look like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellZero", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        /* ... */
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellOne
        /* ... */
        return cell
    } else { //set your last indexPath.row case in "else", not in "else if indexPath.row == 2"!!!
        switch segment {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellTwo
            /* ... */
            return cell
        case 1:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellThree", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellThree
            /* ... */
            return cell
        default: //set your last segment case in "default:", not in "case 2:"!!!
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellFour", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellFour
            /* ... */
            return cell
        }
    }
    //No need for a fictive "return cell" with this code!!!
}
```

If `segment` is not an optional, thanks to *tuples*, you can even reduce the previous code to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch (indexPath.row, segment) {
    case (0, _):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellZero", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        /* ... */
        return cell
    case (1, _):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellOne
        /* ... */
        return cell
    case (2, 0):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellTwo
        /* ... */
        return cell
    case (2, 1):
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellThree", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellThree
        /* ... */
        return cell
    default: //case (2, 2)
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellFour", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CellFour
        /* ... */
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: The `default: //case (2, 2)` bit feels inelegant. Perhaps use `fallthrough`? But I don't even really like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are only declaring the last `var cell: UITableViewCell!` - you are not initialising it. You need to do something like

```
var cell = UITableViewCell(style: someStyle, reuseIdentifier: someID)
return cell
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the cell before your `if...then` logic, then return it after. You don't have to initialize the cell if you use `var`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // ...
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("segmentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        // ...
    } else if indexPath.row == 2 {
        // ...
    } 

    return cell
}
```

(Just make sure you catch all cases - if your return cell without initializing you'll get a runtime error.)